# Saving for loop values to database

Tags: c#, database, gridview, for-loop

I have a gridview to insert values into database, but it's always showing the latest value (i tested using label). I want to have it to input all the values in database (multiple rows) values of each row in grid view to be inserted into multiple rows in the database.

Here's my grid view:

[image]

I need to save every row's value into the database. Here's my code:

```
protected void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (int.TryParse(testLabel.Text, out number))//Click count
    {
        testLabel.Text = (++number).ToString();
    } 

    DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            TextBox box1 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1");
            TextBox box2 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox2");

            Model.question act = new Model.question(); // Entity Model CRUD
            act.Answer = box2.Text;  //Always show the last value.
            act.QuestionContent = box1.Text; // Always show the last value.
            act.TaskName = "Grammar";
            act.ActivityName = dropListActivity.SelectedItem.Text;
            act.QuestionNo = testLabel.Text;

            daoQuestion.Insert(act);       
        }

        daoQuestion.Save(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: What's `ViewState["CurrentTable"]`, is the the source for the GridView ?

Comment: i stored the datatable in viewstate.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: ViewState is usually the wrong place to store a DataTable. Are you aware that ViewState gets sent to the client browser and then back to the server on every PostBack?

Answer (score 1):

TextBox1 and TextBox2 are the same throughout your Grid. By selecting TextBox1 and TextBox2 from different grid doesn't help, you'll just get the values from the same two TextBoxes.

Try adding the TextBoxes to a List and then subsequently, just get their Text and insert into your database.

To add TextBox into a list, you can do this.

```
List<TextBox> tbList = new List<TextBox>();
tbList.Add(new TextBox{ Name="textbox"+i++ });
```

Subsequently, to grab the values out, just do this.

```
for(int i = 0; i < tbList.Count; i++)
{
    //To see the data you're inserting into database.
    Response.Write(tb[i].Text);
    Response.Write(tb[i+1].Text);
    //Insert into database based on your code.
    daoQuestion.Insert(new Model.question 
    { 
        Answer = tb[i].Text,
        QuestionContent = tb[++i].Text,
        TaskName = "Grammar",
        ActivityName = dropListActivity.SelectedItem.Text,
        QuestionNo = testLabel.Text
    });
    daoQuestion.Save();
}
```

Comment: yeah but how do i save every value to database?

Comment: Updated the answer, try it.

Comment: wad does Name in Name=textbox refer to?

Comment: Name is the name of the TextBox. You called it box1 in your question.

Comment: does not contain a definition when i put box1

Comment: Huh? What are you talking about?

Comment: You're welcome. Please post your answer and mark it as **the answer** for the benefit of others.